# Is Xcode 6 necessary to submit new Apps to the App Store?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode5, ios8, xcode6

We are about to release a new version of an existing App to the AppStore this week. I would like to know whether Apple will reject my App because it is not built using Xcode 6.

I have experienced some issues when building the App using Xcode 6 but App works perfectly in all OS's with Xcode 5. To be honest I thought I could submit the App to the store even before the release of iOS 8 and Xcode 6.

We do not have much time now and need to submit the App to store this week itself at any cost.

Please help.

Comment: not it is not still, see itunesconnect, it tells what version of xcode you should use while submitting and it would be always uptime info.

Comment: Thanks nyekimov for the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sep 2014) I just submitted an iOS app tonight, and iTunes Connect stated that Xcode 5.1.1 or newer may be used for submission.

Edit: a comment submitted 28 May 2015 states that Xcode 6 is now the minimum version.

Comment: this answer is no longer valid: Xcode6 is now the minimum requirement https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can build and upload to App Store with xcode 5 
Right now there is not any specific instruction or guideline available which indicates minimum requirement for upload any app build to app store with xcode 6

Comment: Thanks Kal's for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Right now (September 2014) you can submit your apps with both Xcode 5.1.1 and Xcode 6.0. In a few weeks/months Apple will stop accepting submissions with Xcode 5.1.1, so until then you have the best of both worlds.

Going by previous versions, there will most likely be an announcement as to when exactly Apple will request Xcode 6 for submissions over at https://developer.apple.com/news/ - watch that newsfeed.